# Why IE gives "show all content" warning? How to avoid this warning programatically?

Tags: json, https, autocomplete, geonames

I Have implemented jquery autocomplete functionality on HTTPS page and that works fine for all browser except Internet Explorer.

While on IE, it does not shows auto popup list for and shows warning as **"Show all content".**

I have used JSON for cross domain request.

Here is my code :

```
function zipAutoCompletet(prefix){

            jQuery( "#"+prefix+"_zip" ).autocomplete({

       source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON", 
          { 'postalcode_startsWith': request.term, maxRows: 12, style: "full" }, 
          function(data) {
              if(data.postalCodes){
                  var x = $.map( data.postalCodes, function( item ){
                      console.log(item)
                      return {
                                   label: item.placeName + (item.adminCode1 ? ", " + item.adminCode1 : "") + ", " + item.postalCode + ", "+item.countryCode,
                                   value: item.postalCode
                      }
                  });
                  response(x);
              }
          }
        );        
    },
```

Can any one tell me that how can I enable autocomplete in IE also without "show all content" warning??

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent IE from showing that message, you need to have everything secure, i.e. everything should be https.

So the first thing i'd try is changing your json url to https.

```
$.getJSON("https://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON",
```